# How does Gson transform JSON into a bean object with TypeToken?

Tags: gson, deserialization

I was wondering that in the case where Java is pseudo-generic, how could `TypeToken<T>` instantiate a real `T` object? Like:

```java
public class MyList extends TypeToken<ArrayList<Integer>>{}
```

How does Java get objects with generics in the case generic erasure —— to get a `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: Gson does not _use_ type tokens for that. What Gson uses is _Type_ and its subtypes, like `ParameterizedType` and its `getActualTypeArguments` method. There are convenience static factory methods like `TypeToken.getParameterized` that can construct such types, so your token can be replaced with `TypeToken.getParameterized(ArrayList.class, Integer.class)` -- they both represent the same.

Comment: `TypeToken` instances are nothing more than a compile-time checked way to make sure your _`List`_ is parameterized properly with an _`<Integer>`_, and not something like _`<Integer, String>`_. Type tokens analyze their base class parameterization and borrow the type from there since such information is not erased. However, type tokens require new classes and cause some `*.class` files bloat (however, they are safe at compile time), whilst `TypeToken.getParameterized` does not require new classes (but is not compile-time safe and accepts even obviously wrong type parameters).